# Global class between two modules

Tags: angular

I have one main module:

app.component.html

```html
<h1>{{globals.title}}</h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HomeModule,
    NotesModule,
    NgbModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path         : '',
        loadChildren : './home/home.module#HomeModule'
      }, {
        path         : 'notes',
        loadChildren : './notes/notes.module#NotesModule'
      },
      {
        path         : 'error',
        component    : ErrorComponent
      },
      { path         : '**',
        redirectTo   : 'error'
      },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
    ])
  ],
  providers    : [homeService, Globals],
  declarations : [AppComponent, ErrorComponent],
  bootstrap    : [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {
```

app.component.ts

```js
import { Globals } from './Globals';

@Component({
 selector    : 'app-root',
  templateUrl : './app.component.html',
  styleUrls   : ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private globals: Globals){
  }
}
```

two child modules 'HomeModule' and 'NotesModule'. I want to share some Global class for each of these modules and them child components.
In my view I need to have class where I could make some global logic and pass result/variables for all app

I created Global.ts file for it:

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class Globals {
  title: string = '';
}
```

But when I change Global's value(title) in other component, it is not changed is app.component.html:

home.component.ts

```js
mport { Component, OnInit, Input        } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Globals                        } from '../globals';


@Component({
  selector    : 'home-root',
  templateUrl : './home.component.html',
  styleUrls   : ['./home.component.scss']
})

export class HomeComponent {
  constructor(private newService:homeService, private globals: Globals) {
    globals.title = 'Home';
  }
}
```

globals.title is not changed in app.component.html thouh I change it in other components

Comment: do you use lazy loaded modules?

Comment: probably not, Global.ts is seen in any route

Comment: Err, yes, you're using lazy loaded modules: `loadChildren : './notes/notes.module#NotesModule'`. That's lazy loading.

Comment: Can you share `app.component.ts` ? Also why does `HomeComponent` have a property `title` if you are using `globals.title` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use shared module and in import the sharedModule:
SharedModule

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [
   ...
 ],
  declarations: [
  ....
 ],
 exports: [
    ... //export component for shared
 ],
 providers: [
    Global
   ],
 })

export class SharedModule { }
```

in HomeModule

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [
   ...
   SharedModule  //import shared
 ],
 providers: [
  ...
 ],
 declarations: [...]
})

export class HomeModule{}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're injecting Globals as a private class. That means its properties won't be accessible in the template, only in the component. It you import it as public in the constructors you use to inject it, you should be able to access and change its properties without issue.